# Location Updates Not working in iPhone 5 (iOS 7) but working in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cllocationmanager

I was having problem with background location services in my iPhone. So, I decided to test foreground services on my device. The best thing was that even it didn't work.

```
- (IBAction) btnPressed
 {
     [self startStandardUpdates]
 }
- (void)startStandardUpdates
{

    if (nil == self.manager) {
        [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
        self.manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.manager.delegate = self;
        self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
}

- (void)locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
    NSLog(@"Paused");
}

- (void)locationManagerDidResumeLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager
{
   NSLog(@"Resumed");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"Locations : %@",locations);

}
```

After showing three updates it stops. And `- (void)locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates:(CLLocationManager *)manager` is never called as "Paused" is never logged out.

Comment: are you trying in carrier network? simulator works fast.but some issue on device

Comment: Is the device sitting stationary? Your desired locationAccuracy will probably cause it to stop firing in that case after it determines the device is not moving.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo The device was indeed stationary. I have also checked the code with accuracy best. It still stops.

Comment: "Best" accuracy on a stationary device will not change anything, the device is still stationary... unless you're trying to detect vibrations, which :) The simulator fakes it for you. If it works there it probably works. Also... select the coarsest granularity you can accept to avoid wasting battery.

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I was just doing that for fun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the device sitting stationary? If so I think Core Location stops firing based on your desired accuracy once it determines the device has not moved beyond the specified radius. No need to right.

Comment: Can you share any reference for your answer. I just want to be sure. Then I will accept your answer

Comment: I don't have any reference for it... just the last 7 years of iOS programming to go on :) Check out my profile if you want to understand why I might know what I am talking about.... and then again there are the iOS docs for core location which you can check to verify.

Comment: 7 years... You have seen the history being made...  Also, it will be nice if you can give me your email or something else. I am sure you can help me a lot